# Provide a summary sheet based on data from other sheet in same workbook

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I am creating a sheet where I am tracking the working hours of some employees in google sheets. 
Each month I need to provide a summary per employee to sign. Until now I was doing it by hand, but there must be some better way to do it.

A test sheet can be found here, the first sheet is data, the second sheet is the summary I am looking for.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LmJYMqJTEpjSKNY4qFXhLRaBbotj7lUEHauynzHISwg/edit?usp=sharing

Is there any way to use an array formula with some filters for Employee name and a date range to accomplish this?

Comment: Sounds possible but the spreadsheet you shared can not be accessed. Please fix permissions.

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: You can create a copy and then share it (after removing private information).